# Arcade Fighting Game AI

Tags: finite-automata, game-ai

I need to build the AI for an opponent in an arcade style fighting game, very similar to Mortal Kombat.

I don't want to use random moves for the computer, but I would like to have an AI that is harder to beat.

Where can I start looking for resources ? Do you know of any implementation of this sort of project ?

Comment: You almost certainly *don't* want to implement a neural network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about how you play the game.

Ask yourself, under what conditions would I perform certain attacks? When would I block? What do I do when I have low health? When my opponent has low health? Do I become more agressive in one situation over the other? When is it best to use long range versus short range?

Etc.

An AI like this usually only follows a bunch of if/else/then statements, with som randomness added in.

You want it to react quickly so much of anything else (A*, alpha-beta, etc) won't be as useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is an algorithm which depends on statistic and count of shoots in each direction. You can put such logic to calculate how many times enemy kicked you in needed direction and predict future attacks.